# Uniswap With fees Buy / Sell Errors

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, cryptocurrency, uniswap

i'm lately working on a token which presents on Buy / Sell fees.

I've created the smart contract and was able to create the LP on Uniswap but all the times i try to buy or sell with a wallet that would have to pay fees (not excluded from fees) i get an Execution Reverted error from uniswap...

I'm using Uniswap V2 and i cannot get what's wrong as it is supposed to work with fees.

This is my transfer function:

```
     function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
         require(from != address(0), "transfer zero address");
         uint256 fromBalance = balanceOf(from);
         require(fromBalance > 0, "Insufficient Balance!");
         uint256 _fee = 0;

         if (_isExcludedFromFeeWallet[from] || _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[to]) {
          _fee = 0;
         } else {
                 if(from == uniswapV2Pair) {
                 _fee = (amount  * buyTax) / 100;
                 } else if(to == uniswapV2Pair) {
                  _fee = (amount * sellTax) / 100;
          }
       }
   
       _balance[from] -= amount;
       _balance[to] += amount - _fee;

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount - _fee);

         if(_fee > 0) {
          _balance[address(this)] += _fee;

          emit Transfer(from, address(this), _fee);
         }

          }
```

Buy and Sell fees are at the moment setted to 3, so, amount * 3 / 100 is supposed to be the formula resulting in a 3% of the amount, still, there might be something wrong as i'm not able to make it work...

Comment: I know that the  --  if (_isExcludedFromFeeWallet[from] || _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[to]) {
          _fee = 0; --  could be transformed in a ! to avoid some row of codes but that wont fix the problem. I've managed to make it work by setting hardcoded fees inside the transfer function itself. Very small amounts like 10 on sell and 20 on buy as fixed numbers, no calculation on amount value. Still, it doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the transfer function using hardcoded values for the fees as following:

```
 if (_isExcludedFromFeeWallet[from] || _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[to]) {
        _fee = 0;
    } else {
        if(from == uniswapV2Pair) {
        _fee = 1000000000000000000;
    } else if(to == uniswapV2Pair) {
        _fee = 1000000000000000000;
    }
    }
```

And it works... The way i'm calculating the fees in the not working transfer function is the following :

```
uint256 public buyTax = 3;
uint256 public sellTax = 3;

// INCRIMINATED CODE INSIDE TRANSFER FUNCTION STARTS HERE

if (_isExcludedFromFeeWallet[from] || _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[to]) {
      _fee = 0;
     } else {
             if(from == uniswapV2Pair) {
             _fee = (amount  * buyTax) / 100;
             } else if(to == uniswapV2Pair) {
              _fee = (amount * sellTax) / 100;
      }
   }
```

I'm basically doing amount * 3 / 100, which, for me, seems to be the right approach... I'm not finding anything at all around and i just can't get over this lol

Answer (score 0):

The "Execution Reverted" error on Uniswap might be due to issues in your token contract, especially in how fees are handled and Uniswap interactions. Double-check token balance, allowance, fee values, and review the transfer function for possible bugs. Debug with event logs and consider testing in a local development environment. Seek help from the developer community if needed.

Comment: This does not help in any way. As i explained, everything works with hardcoded fees but not with the amount * buy tax / 100 calculation. It has nothing to do with the amount of the fees at all as a lower fees amount still doesn't work if calculated and not hardcoded. The problem must be in the code showed above for sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).